# Why is Visual C++ not performing return-value optimization on the most trivial code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, return-value-optimization

Does Visual C++ not perform return-value optimization?

```
#include <cstdio>
struct Foo { ~Foo() { printf("Destructing...\n"); } };
Foo foo() { return Foo(); }
int main() { foo(); }
```

I compile and run it:

```
cl /O2 test.cpp
test.exe
```

And it prints:

> Destructing...
>       Destructing...

Why is it not performing RVO?

Comment: You might want to ask Microsoft, rather than StackOverflow...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Well [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f8h5cxt.aspx) says they can perform *named* RVO (which is much more difficult), but I was neither able to get NRVO working, nor simple RVO. So I'm feeling I'm doing something wrong here, since if they didn't support it they wouldn't have mentioned it (hopefully...)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Do you have a link to the doc from Microsoft?

Comment: It could be, perhaps, that the compiler is calling the print statement twice, but is still only creating one object.

Comment: @DougRamsey: lol, no, that's impossible and wouldn't make any sense. James knew the reason -- I accidentally told him his solution doesn't work (because I tested it on a debug build by accident) and then he removed the comment. But it was correct. Now I'm just waiting for him to post it as an answer... it's really weird. :)

Comment: I retracted my comment because I had an alternative hypothesis that turned out to be incorrect (I thought a move construction might be occurring instead of RVO, but that is not the case).  I would recommend opening a bug on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio), if the issue is important to you.  Since the issue only appears to affect class types that have no nontrivial constructors, I'm not sure that it's a huge problem (and since RVO is an optional optimization, it's not a conformance issue), but it's still worth reporting.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Thanks for the info. I just tried reporting the bug but when I download the extension, it says the manifest is invalid. I'm not a fan of submitting bug reports to MS just because it's so tedious... :\

Comment: @Mehrdad:  It should be fairly painless and can be done without any plugins.  The direct link to the form is https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx.  Only a Live account is needed.  I've never used the feedback tool, so I can't comment on that.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Oh awesome, thanks! https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/756190/visual-c-return-value-optimization-inhibited-by-trivial-constructor

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When I test with this:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Foo { 
    Foo(Foo const &r) { std::cout << "Copying...\n"; }
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Destructing...\n"; }
    Foo() {}
};

Foo foo() { return Foo(); }

int main() { Foo f = foo(); }
```

...the output I get is:

```
Destructing...
```

No invocation of the copy constructor, and only one of the destructor.

Comment: Hmmm... would you mind explaining what causes the difference between this code and my code?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Somehow, the compiler-generated default constructor seems to inhibit [N]RVO. As soon as you add a default ctor of your own, you get working [N]RVO (e.g., if you add and call: `Foo bar() { Foo f; return f; }`, you just get one more destructor invcation, so NRVO works as well).

Comment: @Mehrdad: Sounds like RVO is only considered when a user-defined constructor exists (probably because that's where it originally mattered), and for whatever reason it isn't considered everywhere.

Comment: The constructor does not necessarily need to be user-declared:  causing `Foo` to have a nontrivial default or copy constructor will also "reenable" RVO (e.g., give it a data member of type `std::string`).

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: :O Where did you learn all this?! I've never seen this information before...

Comment: Bottom line: the compiler only bothers with eliminating copies when there's at least some possibility that copying is expensive enough to be worth eliminating.

Comment: @Ed S.: Also helps to have access to the compiler's source code.

Comment: @XanderTulip: I didn't realize he worked for MS on the VS C++ team :D.  I suppose that would help a bit.