# Lambda expressions and RVO

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, rvo

Is the concept of "Return Value Optimization" applied for lambda expression in C++ Compilers? I know that it depends on the compiler and the optimization parameters but is it theoretical possible?

BTW, does anyone know about this issue in VS.NET 2013 or higher?

Comment: RVO is not applied in VS 2013 ? Do you have the flag /O2 which optimize code for speed ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1ack8f1.aspx

Comment: yes it has but does that mean there is RVO ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can prove it with a little example.

The following code produced this output, when I compiled with clang and g++ with the `-O2` option:

> Ctor

So, "copy" was not printed. This means that **NO** copy happened.

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
    Test() { std::cout << "Ctor\n";}
    Test(const Test& t) 
    {
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{    
    auto myLambda = []() 
    {
        return Test();
    };

    Test t = myLambda(); 
}
```

RVO applies to the return value of a function. A lambda is compiled as a functor. So, it still is a function.

As for why does it not work in VS, maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26968026/5076707) can help you.

Comment: sorry I did not get you... how did you exactly make sure by this example that it is applied?

Comment: The copy constructor is not called only the constructor. So a copy was not made.

Comment: To be meaningful, such code should probably do something with `t` so that the entire program isn't just optimised away to nothing. It _wasn't_ in my case with `g++`, and nor did adding a member `int a{4}` and `cout << t.a` make any difference, so I can confirm your results... but still, when we're measuring optimisations, we should always take steps to make sure _other_ optimisations don't make our measurements meaningless! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> but is it theoretical possible?

I don't see any reason why not. lamda's are on-the-fly compile time generated structs with `()` operator overloaded.

meaning that this :

```
auto f = []{printf("hi");};
```

will probably be translated to

```
struct lambda<someID>{  void operator(){printf("hi");}  };
auto f = lambda<someID>();
```

so, there is no reason why RVO wouldn't work here if the compiler thinks it may optimize things up.